# jquery открытие нового окна

Tags: jquery

как написать на jquery код, который по клике на любой картинке открывает ссылку в новом окне?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите так

```
$('img').each(function() {
   var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
   if(!a.test(this.href)) {
       $(this).click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();
           window.open(this.href, '_blank');
       });
   }
});
```

Лучше так

```
$('img').attr('target','_blank');
```